# How to replace string values in one column with actual column values from other columns in the same dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have some string values in one column and I would like to replace the substrings in that column with values in other columns, and replace all the plus signs with spaces (like below).

I have these `List[String]` mappings which are passed in dynamically where the `mapFrom` and `mapTo` should correlate in index.

Description values: `mapFrom: ["Child Name", "Child Age", "Child State"]`

Column names: `mapTo: ["name", "age", "state"]`

Input example:

```
name, age, state, description
tiffany, 10, virginia, Child Name + Child Age + Child State
andrew, 11, california, Child State + Child Name + Child Age
tyler, 12, ohio, Child Age + Child State + Child Name
```

Expected result:

```
name, age, state, description
tiffany, 10, virginia, tiffany 10 virginia
andrew, 11, california, california andrew 11
tyler, 12, ohio, 12 ohio tyler
```

How can I achieve this using Spark Scala?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [`regexp_replace`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#regexp_replace-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-) to replace substrings with a value from another column.

First, zip the two lists (here I add the change from `+` to space into the two lsits but it can be done separately):

```
val mapFrom = List("Child Name", "Child Age", "Child State") :+ " \\+ "
val mapTo = List("name", "age", "state").map(col) :+ lit(" ")
val mapToFrom = mapFrom.zip(mapTo)
```

Assuming an input dataframe `df`, replace all substrings with their respective value as follows:

```
val df2 = mapToFrom.foldLeft(df){case (df, (from, to)) => 
  df.withColumn("description", regexp_replace($"description", lit(from), to))
}
```

With the provided input data, the result is as expected:

```
+-------+---+----------+--------------------+
|name   |age|state     |description         |
+-------+---+----------+--------------------+
|tiffany|10 |virginia  |tiffany 10 virginia |
|andrew |11 |california|california andrew 11|
|tyler  |12 |ohio      |12 ohio tyler       |
+-------+---+----------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Is there a way to take care of from fields with similar strings?

For example, from("AGE", "AGENT"), to("age", "agent_name")

Comment: @Tiffany I'm not really sure on what the difference is from the above question. You can create a new question where there are some more room to explain and then post a link here so I can take a look at it. :)

Comment: Hey @Shaido, I've posted a new question! Thanks for your help :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57359585/how-to-replace-string-values-in-one-column-with-actual-column-values-from-other

Comment: @Tiffany: No problems, I added an answer to the new question. It seems to be due to the use of "Child" which is a subsequence of the other descriptions (ChildAge and ChildState).