# How to replace string values in one column with actual column values from other columns in the same dataframe? Part 2

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I have some string values in one column and I would like to replace the substrings in that column with values in other columns, and replace all the plus signs with spaces (like below).

I have these `List[String]` mappings which are passed in dynamically where the `mapFrom` and `mapTo` should correlate in index.

Description values: `mapFrom: ["Child", "ChildAge", "ChildState"]`

Column names: `mapTo: ["name", "age", "state"]`

Input example:

```
name, age, state, description
tiffany, 10, virginia, Child + ChildAge + ChildState
andrew, 11, california, ChildState + Child + ChildAge
tyler, 12, ohio, ChildAge + ChildState + Child
```

Expected result:

```
name, age, state, description
tiffany, 10, virginia, tiffany 10 virginia
andrew, 11, california, california andrew 11
tyler, 12, ohio, 12 ohio tyler
```

How can I achieve this using Spark Scala?

When I try the solution from here: [How to replace string values in one column with actual column values from other columns in the same dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56159850/how-to-replace-string-values-in-one-column-with-actual-column-values-from-other/56161195?noredirect=1#comment101159547_56161195)

The output becomes

```
name, age, state, description
tiffany, 10, virginia, tiffany tiffanyAge tiffanyState
andrew, 11, california, andrewState andrew andrewAge
tyler, 12, ohio, tylerAge tylerState tyler
```

Comment: For thw second Row how do you know`ChildState + Child + Child` which one is age and name, How do you know it?

Comment: that was a typo sorry

Comment: I am assuming there is also a typo here: ```tyler, 12, ohio, ChildAge + ChildState + ChildName``` and that this should be ```tyler, 12, ohio, ChildAge + ChildState + Child```, is that correct?

Comment: It looks like `ChildName` in `mapFrom` are actually `Child` while all `ChildName` in the input are actually only `Child`. I edited the question to reflect this, please tell me if it's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `map` instead of built-in Spark functions.
Not the cleanest, but the working solution

```
val data = Seq(
  ("tiffany", 10, "virginia", "ChildName + ChildAge + ChildState"),
  ("andrew", 11, "california", "ChildState + ChildName + ChildAge"),
  ("tyler", 12, "ohio", "ChildAge + ChildState + ChildName")
).toDF("name", "age", "state", "description")
```

Define the schema for encoder conversions

```
val schema = StructType(Seq(
  StructField("name", StringType),
  StructField("age", IntegerType),
  StructField("state", StringType),
  StructField("description", StringType)
))
val encoder = RowEncoder(schema)
```

The logic itself

```
val res = data.map(row => {
  val desc = row.getAs[String]("description").replaceAll("\\s+", "").split("\\+")
  val sb = new StringBuilder()
  val map = desc.zipWithIndex.toMap.map(_.swap)

  map(0) match {
    case "ChildState" => sb.append(row.getAs[String]("state")).append(" ")
    case "ChildAge" => sb.append(row.getAs[Int]("age")).append(" ")
    case "ChildName" => sb.append(row.getAs[String]("name")).append(" ")
  }

  map(1) match {
    case "ChildState" => sb.append(row.getAs[String]("state")).append(" ")
    case "ChildAge" => sb.append(row.getAs[Int]("age")).append(" ")
    case "ChildName" => sb.append(row.getAs[String]("name")).append(" ")
  }

  map(2) match {
    case "ChildState" => sb.append(row.getAs[String]("state")).append(" ")
    case "ChildAge" => sb.append(row.getAs[Int]("age")).append(" ")
    case "ChildName" => sb.append(row.getAs[String]("name")).append(" ")
  }

  Row(row.getAs[String]("name"), row.getAs[Int]("age"), row.getAs[String]("state"), sb.toString())
}) (encoder)
```

Results

```
res.show(false)
+-------+---+----------+---------------------+
|name   |age|state     |description          | 
+-------+---+----------+---------------------+
|tiffany|10 |virginia  |tiffany 10 virginia  |
|andrew |11 |california|california andrew 11 |
|tyler  |12 |ohio      |12 ohio tyler        |
+-------+---+----------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is due to the description containing `Child`. This is a subsequence of `ChildAge` and `ChildState`. Since a regex is used this means that the `Child` part will be replaced by the names resulting in strange outputs such as `tiffanyAge` and `tiffanyState` (note that the `Child` part here is replaced by the name).

There are two simple solutions in this case without changing the input:

1. Change the regex for `Child` to use lookahead:

   ```
   val mapFrom = List("Child(?= )", "ChildAge", "ChildState") :+ " \\+ "
   ```

   This will only match `Child` when there is a space afterwards.
2. Put `Child` last in the list. This means that `ChildAge` and `ChildState` will be matched first:

   ```
   val mapFrom = List("ChildAge", "ChildState", "Child") :+ " \\+ "
   ```

Full solution with the first alternative:

```
val mapFrom = List("Child(?= )", "ChildAge", "ChildState") :+ " \\+ "
val mapTo = List("name", "age", "state").map(col) :+ lit(" ")
val mapToFrom = mapFrom.zip(mapTo)

val df2 = mapToFrom.foldLeft(df){case (df, (from, to)) => 
  df.withColumn("description", regexp_replace($"description", lit(from), to))
}
```